# exclude a form from dxSkinController1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

dxSkinController1 changes the entire application's forms to a selected skin. However, I want some forms excluded. How can I do that ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `TdxSkinController` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on devexpress site :

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B136071

```
procedure SetControlSkinName(AControl: TWinControl; const ASkinName: string);
var
  AIntf: IcxLookAndFeelContainer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Supports(AControl, IcxLookAndFeelContainer, AIntf) then
  begin
    AIntf.GetLookAndFeel.NativeStyle := False;
    AIntf.GetLookAndFeel.SkinName := ASkinName;
  end;
  for I := 0 to AControl.ControlCount - 1 do
    if AControl.Controls[I] is TWinControl then
      SetControlSkinName(TWinControl(AControl.Controls[I]), ASkinName);
end;


procedure TForm1.dxSkinController1SkinForm(Sender: TObject; AForm: TCustomForm;
  var ASkinName: string; var UseSkin: Boolean);
begin
if AForm = Form1 then
  begin
    ASkinName := 'Metropolis';
    UseSkin := True;
    SetControlSkinName(AForm, ASkinName);
end;
end;
```

This actually applies the desired skin to a desired form. To exclude the rest of the form just set dxSkinController1's NativeStyle to false.